# preg_replace with repeating pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

When using preg_replace with repeating pattern, the reference just return the last one. Is there any way to get all?

for example:

```
 $str = "hello, world, hello1, world1"
 echo(preg_replace('/([^,]*,?)+/', '$1', $str));
```

would return **world1**, but is there any way to access to other matched part?

This is just an example, I just want to know if there is any way to access all matched part in reference?

Comment: This is an example, not the real case.

Comment: Can you post the real case, then? Otherwise, our solutions may not work as you expect.

Comment: I asked that in another question, got no answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815843/preg-replace-to-build-query-string-like-array-from-php-like-array

Comment: perhaps you could take a look at `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: preg_replace_callback works the same way, no access to repeating part!!!

Comment: How to do it with preg_split?

Comment: You could also use `print_r(str_getcsv($str));` in that very case.

Comment: @ali: Maybe so, but the callback function of `preg_replace_callback` can be used to check substring repetition etc..

Comment: no, the callback only returns the last match!

Comment: @No, the callback is a function, and the first argument is the entire matched string. the callback returns whatever you want it to return

Comment: I know, but what it gets is the last match for a repeated pattern!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, I went to test my examples, and found that yours doesn't actually work. It needs to be `[^,]+` not `[^,]*` otherwise it eats the input:

```
$str = "hello, world, hello1, world1"
echo preg_replace('/([^,]*,?)+/', '$1', $str);
# -> ""
echo preg_replace('/([^,]+,?)+/', '$1', $str);
# -> " world1"
```

You could capture **all** occurrences, by adding another set of brackets:

```
$str = "hello, world, hello1, world1"
echo preg_replace('/(([^,]+,?)+)/', '$1', $str);
# -> "hello, world, hello1, world1"
```

Or you could replace each individual occurrence, rather than the whole repeating pattern:

```
$str = "hello, world, hello1, world1"
echo preg_replace('/([^,]+,?)/', '$1 AND', $str);
# -> "hello, AND world, AND hello1, AND world1 AND"
```

If neither of those is what you want, then I suspect `preg_replace` is not what you want, and `preg_match_all` might be more appropriate.